# Pathfinding: How to create path data for the pathfiding algorithm?

Tags: javascript, path-finding

I realize this is not strictly related to programming problems but as SO is the best resource for programming related problems, I decided to try it out. :)

I have a project where I need to do 3D pathfinding with javascript, inside a building. Dijkstra algorithm is probably the best case for this, as it handles irregular shapes quite nicely.

However, the problem is this:
Dijkstra requires node structure for it to work. But how to create that data? Obviously some sort of conversion need to be done from the basedata, but how to create that basedata? Going through the blueprint, getting x & y values for each possible path node, calculating the distances by hand seems bit excessive... And prone for swearwords...

I was even thinking of using Google Scetchup for this. Drawing lines for each possible path, but then the problem is getting the path data out from it. :/

I can't be the first person to have this problem... Any ideas? Are there any ready-made tools for creating path data?

Comment: If you have a some kind of a 3D-model of the building (as a dwg), you could draw the paths in it as polylines, and then save these polylines to a dxf-file. dxf-file contains the drawing data in a text format, and vertices are easy to extract. For the task you'll need AutoCAD or some other application which reads/writes dwgs and dxfs. I've done something like this years ago, but unfortenately I don't have that JavaScript code anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find any ready made tools so I ended up creating the path data as lines in Google SketchUp, exporting them Collada files and writing my own converter for the Collada XML data.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be done in code by constructing a 3d grid and removing cubes that intersect with 3d objects.

I would then layer multiple 3d grids (doubling in size each time) that gives a more general idea of reachability (constructed from smaller grids), then by sheer virtue of path finding algorithms you will always find the most efficient path from A-B that will automatically direct the path using the largest cells (and therefore the fewest calculation steps). **Note**: make the larger 3d grids have a slightly lower weighting so that it's paths are favoured.

This can be used for many applications. For example if you could only walk on the ground, then simply remove blocks in unreachable areas.